# MailChimp for WordPress Redirect

Tags: wordpress, forms, redirect, mailchimp

I'm using the [MailChimp for WordPress plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/mailchimp-for-wp/) and would like to re-direct to a new page on submit if possible?

Here's the code I've been trying to use:

```
<p>
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" required="required" placeholder="Your name" name="FNAME">
</p>
<p>
    <label for="mc4wp_email">Email address: </label>
    <input type="email" id="mc4wp_email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Your email address" required />
</p>

<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign up" />
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/test"> 
</p>
```

I've tried adding that hidden input to re-direct but it hasn't worked from me, would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you forget to look at the plugin settings?
Navigate to Mailchimp for WP > forms, scroll down to "Redirect to URL after successful sign-ups".